# Template field missing in page attributes

Tags: pages, templates

Hi I ma trying to assign a template to a Wordpress them. There is no such option as per attachment??Changing the theme does not help...Thanks for the help[image]

Comment: Do the themes you tried actually have page templates having the `Template Name` [comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)? And if you're trying to make your own custom template, you should add that comment to your template. Also, for post types other than `page`, you should also add the `Template Post Type` line.

Comment: Hi, I tried it with joomla but now it works on Yoko.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar a few days ago when doing changes on my custom theme.

If you put a file directly in the folder of your theme

```
themes
|_ bt
  |_ contact-me.php
```

The `contact-me.php` structure

```
<?php defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

// Template name: Contact me
```

It will be available

If you put it into a folder directly in your theme

```
themes
|_ bt
  |_ pages
    |_ contact-me.php
```

It will be available

Apparently any deeper than that and wordpress can't find it, so if you have a folder structure similar to this.

```
themes
|_ bt
  |_ pages
    |_ contact
      |_ contact-me.php
```

It wont be available.